# How to read the XML from an Android layout file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Consider the following XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Text"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I would like to read this file line by line similar to reading a text file. I am not looking for an XML parser. How can I do this?

I managed to use XmlResourceParser, but there is a problem. I don't want to parse field by field, I just want to pull all data out.

Comment: may i kindly ask to specify your question more please ? This whole xml is a string, and you would like to read/parse ?

Comment: What *exactly* are you asking? What do you want to do and why a String?

Comment: @codeMagic imagine that I want to send the xml layout to another service

Comment: You still aren't explaining enough. What would you do with it in that service and why would you need to? From what I'm reading in your question, you are likely trying to do something in a way that you shouldn't be.

Comment: @codeMagic in the same way you can read/open a raw resource, how can I do it with a layout resource?

Comment: Do you want to read the XML layout using a webservice which is sent from the server?

Comment: @Ali, no, i just want to read the resource.

Comment: if you want to extract the xml-resource from the android-apk file this is a duplicate of [How to read compiled xml files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480704/how-to-read-compiled-xml-files/11386195)

Comment: @k3b I want to read it in app run time, I'm not trying to reverse engineer an apk.

Comment: do you want to write an android app that can read other apk-s-layout-xml-s? can you tell us what you already have and what stopped you? by add the missing problem details from the comments to the question will improve the likelyhood that other readers can help you finding a solution.

Comment: Are you trying to read the text from a TextView? What do you need to read from the XML file?

Comment: @McAdam331 I want to read all the content from the layout

Comment: So you want to read from the XML file, in the same way you might read from a text file or something?

Comment: @McAdam331 line by line for example, I manage to use XmlResourceParser, but there is a problem, i don't want to parse field by field,  I just want to pull all data out

Comment: @letz I believe I understand now. I think your question was very unclear. I have tried to edit it. If it is not what you intended, please edit with your exact intentions and try to give an example of how/why you would use it so it is easier for others to understand.

Comment: @McAdam331 thanks, that is exactly what I as trying to ask

Comment: you can't, the xml files are compiled in a binary-like format during compilation of the app

Comment: @njzk2 so only with the parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible when the xml is located in res/layout folder, the xml files are compiled in a binary-like format during compilation of the app.

Comment: Not true if you store the xml in `res/raw`

Comment: @BrianAttwell my goal here is to read from res/layout folder, not from res/raw

Answer (score 0):

You can store xml files as assets without them being compiled. You need to store them in the `res/raw` directory. For example, take a look at the following tutorial

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/27/using-files-as-raw-resources-in-android/

Comment: Yeah but its not the use case where